# Paley Zygmund inequality, why positive?

Tags: probability, inequality, distribution-tails

Paley Zygmund inequality states that:

$$P(Z> \theta E[Z]) \ge (1-\theta)^2\frac{E[Z]^2}{E[Z^2]}.$$

Throughout the internet and text books, it is stated for a non-negative random variable Z (i.e. $Z\ge 0$). But, it seems the proof straightly follow if we only assume $E[Z]>0$. Indeed, the first step is

$Z= Z\mathbf{1}_{Z\le \theta E[Z]} + Z\mathbf{1}_{Z> \theta E[Z]}$  hence

$E[Z] \le  \theta E[Z] + E[Z\mathbf{1}_{Z> \theta E[Z]}]$. So far, no assumptions over $Z$.

Next we apply C.S (which also doesn't require assumptions on $Z$):
$E[Z] \le  \theta E[Z] + \sqrt{E[Z^2]P(Z > \theta E[Z])}$.
Which leads to:
$$\sqrt{P(Z>\theta E[Z])} \ge (1-\theta)\frac{E[Z]}{\sqrt{E[Z^2]}}.$$

So far there were no assumptions on $Z$ (other than $E[Z^2]\ne 0$, which follows from $E[Z]>0$).
Now we want to take the square of both sides, which indeed requires the two sides to be positive, which only requires $E[Z]>0$.

Why is Paley-Zygmund then, formulated to positive random variables?
Does anyone know a reference that states it without the positivity requirement?

Comment: Right, $EZ >0$ is enough.

Comment: Are $\Theta$ and $\theta$ the same thing and is it assumed to be constant?

Comment: yes, sorry for the confusion. Edited it.

Comment: Consider $Z$ a gaussian random variable with mean $1$ and variance $1$, then by the inequality $\mathbb{P}(Z > 1/100) \ge (1-1/100)^2 \approx 0.98$ by the inequality, however, $\mathbb{P}(Z > 1/100) \le 0.9$. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+from+1%2F100+to+infty+of+e%5E%28-%28x-1%29%5E2%2F2%29%2F+sqrt%282+pi%29+

Comment: Variance 1, don't you mean $E[|Z-1|^2]=1$? In that case you have $E[Z^2]=2$ and the inequality states:

$P(Z>1/100) \ge \frac{(1-1/100)^2}{2} \approx 0.49$

Comment: yeah you are right, my bad.